# How To Make a Create Box-Shadow Wrapper For A Div Element?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I'm trying to put a box-shadow wrapper around a box element.

I copied the box element's code, `hid all the visible styles` and added a `box-shadow`. But that scattered various page elements all over the place.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "middleAreaWrap"> 
    <div class = "mainButtons"">
        <div id = 'FirstRowButtons'">
            <button class = "ButtonOne"">ButtonOne</button>
            <button class = "buttonTwo""> ButtonTwo </button>
        </div>
        <div id = 'SecondRowButtons'">
            <button class = "ButtonThree"">ButtonThree</button>
            <button class = "buttonFour""> ButtonFour </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*BUTTON AREA DIV */
.mainButtons {
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: #B9B5B4;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 74%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 49px;
    height: 30%;
}

/*BUTTON AREA DIV WRAP */
.middleAreaWrap {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 74%;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 15px #B9B5B4;*/
    bottom: 49px;
    height: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you mean but the inner box is positioned absolutely so removing `bottom: 49px` from `.mainButtons` will prevent page elements from being scattered all over the place:

```css
 /*BUTTON AREA DIV */
   .mainButtons {
        z-index: 3;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        border: 10px solid;
        border-style: groove;
        border-color: #B9B5B4;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 74%;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        padding: 10px;

        height: 30%;
        }

 /*BUTTON AREA DIV WRAP */
     .middleAreaWrap {
        z-index: 1;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        border: 10px hidden;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 74%;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 15px #B9B5B4;*/
        bottom: 49px;
        height: 30%;
        }
```

```html
<div class = "middleAreaWrap"> 
<div class = "mainButtons"">

    <div id = 'FirstRowButtons'">
      <button class = "ButtonOne"">ButtonOne</button>
      <button class = "buttonTwo""> ButtonTwo </button>
    </div>

    <div id = 'SecondRowButtons'">
      <button class = "ButtonThree"">ButtonThree</button>
      <button class = "buttonFour""> ButtonFour </button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```